# The cvQueryFrame function call slows the main loop execution using OpenCV and OpenGL

Tags: opengl, opencv, opengl-3

I coded a simple program below which get the video stream from a webcam and diplays it on the screen. Until here all is ok (when I move the camera all is synchronized). But I want also display in the same time a colored triangle in permanent rotation. The trouble is that the rotation is very slow. The problem comes from the cvQueryFrame call (If I erase the cvQueryFrame call, of course I have no video on my window but the triangle rotates correctly). I know that this function makes some heap allocations and heap allocations are very bad in a main loop. But in an another side I have to get the next frame at each loop occurence. When the application is launched, if I move the camera the image is synchronized with my movements but the rotation of the model is slow. So it not seems to be a frame rate problem (in my opinion, if it was the case, the video should not be synchronized with my movements).

Here's my C++ code :

```
#define GL_WINDOW_WIDTH 500
#define GL_WINDOW_HEIGHT 500

float angle = 0.0f;

int             main(void)
{
    if (!glfwInit())
        return (-1);

    //Window initialization

    if (!glfwOpenWindow(GL_WINDOW_WIDTH, GL_WINDOW_HEIGHT, 8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0, GLFW_WINDOW)) {
        glfwTerminate();
        return (-1);
    }

    //Projection

    glViewport(0,0, GL_WINDOW_WIDTH, GL_WINDOW_HEIGHT) ;
    glEnable(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0f, 500.0f / 500.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    gluLookAt(0.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    CvCapture   *capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(CV_CAP_ANY);
    IplImage    *frame = NULL;

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION) ;
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluPerspective(45.0f, GL_WINDOW_WIDTH / GL_WINDOW_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    gluLookAt(0.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    //Main loop

    while (1)
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT) ;

        //Get next video frame

        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);

        //Draw video frame

        glDrawPixels(frame->width, frame->height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, frame->imageData);

        //Triangle transformations

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW) ;
        glLoadIdentity() ;

        glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(angle, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        //Render triangle

        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glColor3ub(255, 0, 0);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glColor3ub(0, 255, 0);
        glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glColor3ub(0, 0, 255);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glEnd();

        glPopMatrix();

        glfwSwapBuffers();

        angle++;

        if ( (cvWaitKey(10) & 255) == 27 ) break;
    }
    cvReleaseImage(&frame);
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
    cvDestroyWindow("mywindow");

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

So I think there is a problem of synchronization between OpenCV and OpenGL but I'm not sure about that.  Does anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found where my problem comes from. I own a logitech C210 with a debit of 15 FPS. The cvQueryFrame function 'waits' the next frame at each call, hence for each loop iteration. So it's normal that my triangle is rotating slowly in comparaison with the execution of the program without the cvQueryFrame call (about 120 FPS). So the solution for me is to buy a new webcam providing a better FPS rate (for example, 60 FPS should be better !). I hope this response will help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and what you can do is make the rotation independent from the FPS.

Something like this:

```
static double lastTime = glfwGetTime();
double currentTime = glfwGetTime();
float deltaTime = float(currentTime - lastTime);
...
angle += deltaTime * speed;
...
lastTime = currentTime;
```